# ng-packagr npm install error : postinstall `opencollective postinstall`

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ng-packagr

I am trying to build an angular 6 library and it needs ng-packagr as a dependency.
I am getting following error while trying to npm install ng-packagr (latest version)

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ng-packagr@4.7.0 postinstall: `opencollective postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-packagr@4.7.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

There is a issue created already in [Github](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1178). Issue is coming from a internal dependency of **ng-packagr** called **opencollective/opencollective-postinstall**. I have tried disabling it in environment variables `DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE=true`.
But i still get the above error. Anyone else has a way around to install ng-packagr?

Comment: Did you solve your problem by now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to install ng-packagr on Alpine Linux. I could solve it by running `apk add ncurses` and installing `ncurses`, because it contains the `tput` command which is required for the `opencollective postinstall`.